# Iterate Over List of Protocol Objects

Tags: ios, swift, loops, inheritance, swiftui

I'm trying to iterate over a list of protocol objects, but I'm running into some issues. I could be going about the inheritance the wrong way. Any help is appreciated.

For example:

Given a property: `var rows: [any CLRow]`

I want to iterate over it:

```
ForEach(rows) { row in
                    
}
```

But that yields an error:

> Type 'any CLRow' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

CLRow is defined as:

```
protocol CLRow: View {
    var label: String { get set }
    var icon: String { get set }
    var showChevron: Bool { get set }
}
```

And I'm trying to do some inheritance with other objects. Example:

```
struct CLDoubleLabelRow: CLRow
```

Comment: I think you need `protocol CLRow: View, Identifiable {…}`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. I get the same error if Identifiable is listed or not.

Comment: SwiftUI requires concrete types for view builders and wrappers.